# Fail to install Spyder 3.3.6 in Anaconda with Python 3.5 version

Tags: python, anaconda

I created a new environment in Anaconda choosing Python 3.5 as the version. As I continue installing the Spyder software through clicking the "Install" button within Anaconda interface, I receive the following message:

> python==3.3.6 cannot be installed on this environment. Do you want to install the package in an existing environment or...."

I even tried clicking setting → install specific version → and choose other versions yet wit the same warning.

Appreciate your very kind help.

Answer (score 1):

I just run into the same problem.
Run:

```
conda install spyder
```

from the environment terminal

Comment: Hello. While I will try this tonight, I do not understand why we need to try this workaround but not able to install it in the normal way from Anaconda interface?